# The safest way to avoid SQL injection in PHP?

Tags: php, security, sql-injection

I just wonder if this line of code is safe to use to avoid SQL injection?

```
// username and password sent from form 
$myusername=$_POST['loginUserName']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['loginPassword'];

$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
```

Do I need to stripslashes?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's safer to use prepared statements, so that the (potentially malicious) values are separated from the query string, rather than relying on escaping.  Read about [PHP Data Objects](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Regarding `stripslashes()`, that should only be necessary if you have PHP's `magic_quotes_gpc` feature turned on, which you [shouldn't](http://www.php.net/manual/en/security.magicquotes.whynot.php) because it's deprecated.  If you want to be robust, though, do `if (get_magic_quotes_gpc()) $myusername = stripslashes($myusername);` so that it removes a layer of slashes if and only if one was added.